# Converting String to Html in Play Framework

Tags: java, html, casting, playframework

I have a simple view (Play! template) that accepts an Html object. I know now that this object is play.twirl.api.Html (in Java). In the controller I want to render.

`return ok(layout.render("<h1> something </h1>"));`

I'm using Play! 2.3.x

But I fail to find a valid conversion from String to Html. I've tried casting and setting the String as the ctor argument for a new Html object but all failed. I have found no documentation on the twirl api.

**Here is my question:**
How do I convert a String to Html in Play! (Java) without changing the template?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You have two possibilities (anyway in both you need to modify your template)

**First** is escaping HTML src within the view:

```
public static Result foo() {
    return ok(foo.render("<h1>Foo</h1>"));
}
```

View `foo.scala.html`:

```
@(myHeader: String)

@Html(myHeader)
```

**Second** is passing ready-to-use `Html` param:

```
import play.twirl.api.Html;

//....

public static Result bar() {
    return ok(bar.render(Html.apply("<h1>Bar</h1>")));
}
```

View `bar.scala.html`

```
@(myHeader: Html)

@myHeader
```

Comment: May I ask you where you learned this? I always seem to fail to find this sort of stuff. Where is a reference (full) of the entire API? It's nowhere to be found and rather frustrating.

Comment: First approach (`@Html(param)`) comes from Play's docs, second from deducation (tip: IntelliJ with Play 2 support + downloaded sources helps a lot) ;)